# cronjob to run shell script and execute npm command on raspberry pi (as opposed to calling node directly)

Tags: node.js, npm, cron, raspberry-pi

I am trying to build a shell script which can be called via a cronjob to trigger an npm nodejs application.

This is my start.sh shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/local/bin/npm
cd /home/lharby/sites/mysite
npm run start
```

If I cd to this folder and execute `./start.sh` the command appears to run. (Path to bash and npm are both correct after checking `which npm`).

My cron job looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/lharby/sites/mysite/start.sh >> /home/lharby/sites/mysite/src/log/cron-errors.txt 2>&1
```

This is throwing an error and additionally I was lead to believe that using `>>` would append to the file, it seems to overwrite it each time.

My guess is that trying to run this command via cron it cannot access certain environment variables that are set up in my index.js

For example:

```
const config = {
    access_token: process.env.NEXT_MASTODON_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    client_key: process.env.NEXT_MASTODON_CLIENT_KEY,
    client_secret: process.env.NEXT_MASTODON_CLIENT_SECRET,
    timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,
    api_url: 'https://botsin.space/api/v1/',
};

const M = new Mastodon(config);
```

I believe I see the same issue when I try to run `node index.js` from `/home/sites/lharby/mysite/src/`

As my `package.json` has this configuration:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/index.js --experimental-modules",
    "temp": "node ./src/temp.js --experimental-modules"
},
```

I was exploring looking at just trying to run the whole app passing in `node index.js` and passing in the argument flags but I need to be able to run the cron file invoking npm rather than node, as I guess that creates a wrapper and npm can access `process.env` variables.

From my cron-errors.txt file I am seeing this:

```
/home/lharby/sites/mysite/node_modules/mastodon-api/lib/mastodon.js:345
                    throw new Error('Mastodon config must include \'' + reqKey + '\' when using \'user_auth\'');
                    ^

Error: Mastodon config must include 'access_token' when using 'user_auth'
    at /home/lharby/sites/glyphbot/node_modules/mastodon-api/lib/mastodon.js:345:27
//
//
/home/lharby/sites/mysite/start.sh: line 4: npm: command not found
/bin/sh: 1: /home/sites/glyphbot/start.sh: not found
/bin/sh: 1: /home/sites/glyphbot/start.sh: not found
```

How can I ensure the crontab will invoke npm? I feel like I am doing everything correctly.

**EDIT**

My issues are:

1. How to run a node project using npm from a cron job?
2. Can the cronjob access environment variables from the npm command?
3. Should `>> cron-errors.txt 2>&1` append the file rather than replace the content each time.

**UPDATE 19.01.23**

So I added exports for my variables to the `.bashrc` file. And when checking `echo $NEXT_MASTODON_ACCESS_TOKEN` I am seeing my string value.

Updated my `.sh` file so it now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
node ./src/index.js --experimental-modules
```

And updated my cronjob to read this:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/lharby/sites/mysite/start.sh >> /home/lharby/sites/mysite/src/log/cron-errors.txt 2>&1
```

And I tried this also trying to bypass the shell script

```
*/5 * * * * /home/lharby/sites/mysite/src && /usr/local/bin/node index.js --experimental-modules >>/home/lharby/sites/mysite/src/log/cron-errors.txt 2>&1
```

It still failed with the same message being logged to the cron-errors.txt file.

However I am now able to run this command invoking node with argument flags (rather than using the npm command) So in the terminal I can type

`node index.js --experimental-modules`

As well as just running the `.sh file` I just don't understand why it is not passing this information to my cronjob.

I don't understand how if my code reads:

`process.env.NEXT_MASTODON_ACCESS_TOKEN,`

Will this get replaced or read by the bash export value instead?

Answer (score 1):

Where are your environment variables being set up?  It looks like your cron is at least running as expected, and your only problem is to get those env variables into the script correctly.  My guess is that you need to use "export" (see bullet point 3)

I would debug this in a few different ways.

1. you should verify that it is the case that your index.js is not able to read your environment variables.  I would recommend adding `console.log(JSON.stringify(config, undefined, 2))` to check this.
2. you should verify that the SHELL has access to those variables before it runs the script.  for this just run `echo $NEXT_MASTODON_ACCESS_TOKEN` (and similar for each variable) to verify if that is the case.
3. environment variables are a little funny.  Assuming you set these values in your .bashrc with `NEXT_MASTODON_ACCESS_TOKEN="whateverTheValueIs"`, just setting variables like this only affects your current process.  In order for sub-processes to have the variable you need to export: `export NEXT_MASTODON_ACCESS_TOKEN="insertValueHere"`

Hope this helps!

Edit:
It's a little unclear what your current issues are, so it might be helpful if you bullet point each issue you are trying to solve

Comment: another thought, the shebang at the top of your script should just be
`#! /bin/bash`.  This basically is a declaration that says what program to run the file through.  By putting `usr/local/bin/npm` right afterward you may be causing the subsequent lines in your script to be ran as npm commands.

Comment: OK thanks so much for this, I will try and step through and see if I can make progress. I would rather read the env variables from config if that is possible as I have 6. But maybe it wouldn't be the end of the world to add them to the export option

Comment: It's not clear from the original question statement where your environment variables were being declared so I just kind of took a guess!  If you gimme some details I might be able to point you in a better direction

Comment: There are in an .env file in the root of the application. And they are read using the dotenv npm dependency

`NEXT_MASTODON_CLIENT_KEY=string1
NEXT_MASTODON_CLIENT_SECRET=string2
NEXT_MASTODON_ACCESS_TOKEN=string3`

Comment: Actually everything is in github apart from the env file, so I can point to that if you really want it.

Comment: I have made some progress, but the cron is still failing. I will try and update my question at some point soon.